# What are the dungeons to go out of the way and to keep an eye on?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've recently reached the lvl on which I can attempt my first dungeon: [Ascalonian Catacombs](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ascalonian_Catacombs).

Now, I've heard some people mention that this is actually one of the harder instances and that the second instance: [Caudecus Manor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Caudecus%27s_Manor) is an easier dungeon for a first-time dungeon delver.

This question is two-fold:

- What would be the dungeons to stay away from until a later lvl than advertised?
- What are some of the easier dungeon that a new player can have hopes for completing?

(If this question should be 2 questions, I'll gladly remove one question and ask it in a different post.)

Comment: Very true. AC is annoying as all get out. CM, however, is quite enjoyable.

Comment: I found the exact opposite. CM was way too easy, and I enjoyed the AC atmosphere/difficulty.

Comment: Off topic, but interesting. I found the difficulty of dungeons in descending order as follow: TA > SE > AC > HoW = CoF = Arah > CoE > CM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no point in not attempting a dungeon when you first reach it. While some dungeons may be more difficult than others, it is a matter of skill (primarily twitch reactions), rather than actual level.

Story Mode should be attempted at the level it is given, and possibly even a few levels below depending on the party.

Exploration Mode should be attempted 5 levels after story mode, and is typically more difficult.

Dungeons offer a variety of rewards, including a great deal of experience and equipment. Ascalonian Catacombs, or AC, takes up to two whole hours for newer players. As a result, it's fairly frustrating and the rewards are fairly low-key. If you enjoy a challenge, or you play with a group of people, there's no reason to skip it. I found this to be the most enjoyable dungeon of them all.

Dungeons such as Caudecus Manor and Citadel of Fire, a level 70 dungeon, can be farmed on exploratory mode easily for Seals and experience/money. These runs typically take less than half an hour, depending on the chosen options, and the seals can be traded in for armor (level 70 rares, or 80 exotics).

TL:DR - Dungeons aren't designed to be impossible, and most are extremely easy.